# Why prefer LongListSelector over Listbox in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

The question is in the title, why is LongListSelector preferred over Listbox, even for creating flat lists in Windows phone 8?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even if you only want to display flat data, the `LongListSelector` is preferable because:

- It provides an optional header and footer.
- The performance of a `LongListSelector` is better than that of a `ListBox`.
- The `LongListSelector` supports full data and UI virtualization.

See the [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/microsoft.phone.controls.longlistselector%28v=vs.105%29.aspx) reference for further information.

Comment: Can you just explain the last point of your answer, what is meant by full data and UI virtualization?

Comment: You can read about it here: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh994637.aspx , in short, UI virtualization creates the UI elements that represent each item in a collection on demand, so if there are 1000 elements, it will not load all of them into memory, only the ones that the user is viewing or is about to view.